# assign value from environment variable to alist

Tags: emacs, environment-variables, elisp

I run Emacs in both office and home, while in office it is behind a firewall.

An environment variable `http_proxy` is only defined in my office PCs, I want my Emacs to check if environment variable `http_proxy` is not empty, if that is the case then use its value to setup `url_proxy_service`. So I tried something like this

```
 (setq proxy (getenv "http_proxy"))
 (setq url-proxy-services
    '(("http" . proxy)
      ("https" . proxy)))
```

I can see `proxy` picks up the value in environment variable `http_proxy`, but `url-proxy-services` becomes `(("http" . proxy) ("https" . proxy))`.

So it looks to me `proxy` is not dereferenced but used as a string literal, what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) to evaluate `proxy` while quoting the list:

```lisp
(setq proxy (getenv "http_proxy"))
(setq url-proxy-services
      `(("http"  . ,proxy)
        ("https" . ,proxy)))
```